# datejs timezone no time component

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a time component to display for EST (UTC-0500) and displayed in the following format Wed 4:12 PM.

I am using datejs library and the toString format mask of "ddd h:mm" which works fine.

However when I set the timezone of the date to be EST there is no longer any minutes shown - it is always 00. ie Wed 4:00 PM.

js code is below

```
var newyork = Date.today();
newyork.setTimezone("EST")   
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=newyork
```

Comment: Date.today ()
Gets a date that is set to the current date. The time is set to the start of the day (00:00 or 12:00 AM). This is from the documentation. In the case of the method today(), therefore, you are getting a time exactly on the hour, i.e. with no minutes

Comment: Ah brilliant! I've just tried that again now with var newyork = new Date() but now the timezone is off - ie EST at this moment in time should be 5:49 but its brining back 3:49

Comment: Try `newyork.setTimezone("ET");` . New York only uses _Eastern Standard Time (EST)_ when **NOT** in daylight savings time. It uses  _Eastern Daylight Time (EDT)_ for daylight savings. All year round it is considered to be in _Eastern Time (ET)_.